# How to configure a named resource stream using OData in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am creating OData endpoints using ASP.NET Web API using v5.8.0 of [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/5.8.0) NuGet package. I have everything working and I can retrieve simple data such as strings and ints without an issue. However I would now like to extend one of the endpoints so that one of the items that can be retrieved is a binary image file. Having read up on OData I have decided to use named resource streams to achieve this.

The problem I have is that I can find very little information on how to implement this using the ODataController. The closest I can find is [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrtechnocal/archive/2013/12/31/10462258.aspx) but it is using an older version of Web API and the code does not compile when I use it in my project.

So can somebody please supply a working example of how this should be implemented please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named streams (aka stream properties) are not currently supported in Web API OData (for OData v4). See the following issues:

- [Clarify the situation for streams](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/574)
- [Document for Stream Support in OData V4](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/328)